# Why is India known as the largest democratic nation?

Tags: democracy, india

Why only India is regarded as the largest democracy, why not the USA or the European Union?

Comment: I'm guessing because it's bigger than either of those?

Comment: @Coditoergosum, actually I believe that there is an interesting story to be told how India managed to **become known** as the world's largest democracy, to the point that foreign journalists repeat that phrase whenever they need a soundbite about Indian elections. Compare the US calling itself the oldest democracy, which is true if one adopts a suitable definition of democracy ...

Answer (score -4):

**India** is rightly termed as the largest democracy because of its sheer size. Look at the number of people getting benefitted by democratic rule- around 1.2 billion second only to China and with an area of 3.287 million km². The Gross Domestic Product(GDP) of **India** is $287 trillion(2019) behind only the USA, China, Japan, Germany, and also European Union if considered as one entity...

Not just that, apart from **India**, in terms of sheer size, only **the USA** comes second whose GDP is $21,42 trillion and the population is nearly 320 million with an area of 9.834 million km².

And the question about the **European Union** is that it is a union with a population of 446 million and a total area of 4.476 million km², not a country though it is democratic but still not one entity..it is a group of nations, not one nation. It has a GDP(excluding UK) of $18.292 trillion of which the largest contributor is **Germany**(3.449 trillion), **France**(2.425 trillion), **Italy**(1,789 trillion) and **Spain**(1.244 trillion), and previously(before Brexit) the **United Kingdom of Great Britain**($2.638 trillion)

**China** is not a democracy. It is a communist-ruled nation. It never has democracy in its entire history. Though it has a staggering economy of $1,434 trillion(2019) and a population of 1.394 billion.

**Russia** is a federation and there is hardly any democracy prevalent there, due to its communist past has an economy of $1.4 trillion and a population of 146.2 million. It has a semi-presidential rule and the President(Vladimir Putin) is the head of the state.

India hence is called the world's largest democracy by its sheer size and great economic growth in recent years.

Comment: The answer should concentrate on two issues -- definitions of size and definitions of a democracy. For this question, either population or voting population are the significant size indicators. Only China is larger, so the question would be answered by showing that India is a democracy and China is not.